# Node.js Vanilla Routes Req.on not sending response

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a vanilla Node.js server to handle the backend of my React Native App.

I am using Http.createServer module, and inside this I am just using normal logic to determine the URL of the request, and then I have postRoutes classes etc to handle the logic like this:

```
const server = http.createServer(async (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const auth = new Authentication(req.headers["authorization"]);
    if (req.method === "GET") {

    } else if (req.method === "POST") {

        if (req.url === "/test") {
            auth.validateToken();

            if (auth.getValidateMessage() === "Unauthorized") return res.end(auth.getValidateMessage());
            return res.end("Hello")
        }

        // If no data is passed to the post route, then this will not run, and the request does not get a response
        req.on('data', async (chunk: { toString: () => string | number; }) => {

            if (req.url === "/register") {
                const response: RouteResponseClass = await PostRoutes.register(chunk);
                if (response.statusCode === 200) return res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
                if (response.statusCode === 400) return res.end(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                return res.end(response.message);
            }

            if (req.url === "/login") {
                const response: RouteResponseClass = await PostRoutes.login(chunk);
                if (response.statusCode === 200) return res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
                if (response.statusCode === 400) return res.end(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                return res.end(response.message);
            }
        });
        // This will always hit first before req.on
    }

    // This will always hit first before req.on
    return res.end("hey")

});
```

**My question is this:**

As we can see, I am using the `req.on` function, that calls a callback when it receives data.

This works properly when receiving data through these routes for example on /login.

**However:** When the user does not send in any data (which shouldn't happen), then the request does not end, as it does not hit the req.on callback function, and nothing is left to handle it.

**What I have tried:** If i set a `res.end` outside the `POST method` then it ends the request before it hits the `req.on` since `req.on` is asynchronous.

How does one handle no data being sent into the post route while using `req.on`?

Thank you for your time everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the logic inside your post handler a bit. In the `.on("data")` callback simply gather all the chunks that are sent in the request and add a `.on("end")` listener in order to be notified when all data from the request body has been consumed (this will immediately fire if the request body is empty). Inside that callback you can then handle sending the response. Something like this:

```
// ...
} else if (req.method === "POST") {
// ...
let bodyBuffer = [];
req.on('data', chunk => {
    bodyBuffer.push(chunk);
});

req.on('end', () => {
    // convert the gathered chunks to string
    const body = bodyBuffer.toString("utf8");
    if (req.url === "/register") {
        const response: RouteResponseClass = await PostRoutes.register(body);
        if (response.statusCode === 200)
            return res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        if (response.statusCode === 400)
            return res.end(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        return res.end(response.message);
    }

    if (req.url === "/login") {
        const response: RouteResponseClass = await PostRoutes.login(body);
        if (response.statusCode === 200)
            return res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        if (response.statusCode === 400)
            return res.end(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        return res.end(response.message);
    }
});
```

Also you can save yourself a lot of pain if you use a framework like [express](https://expressjs.com/) to do this.